# How to expand and collapse in WPF like in webpage

Tags: c#, wpf

Is anyone familiar with websites that have an attribute similar to a tree-view? Like the download segment of the Microsoft website. You press the plus button, it expands and everything below it moves further down. You press the minus button and everything in that block collapses and the content below shifts back up.

Granted C# is nothing like HTML and CSS but I just wanted to know if it was possible to do the same in a WPF application.

It seems like the tree-view currently in the tool box allows for text only to be implemented. It doesn't allow for additional objects such as labels or text-boxes.

I discovered the EXPANDER and it does a good job of expanding and collapsing its content's but isn't quite capable of pulling objects beneath it back up or pushing them back down. Here's an example of the scenario I would like.

[image: exibitA]
[image: exibitB]

An example of what I'm going for would be [microsoft's download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) if it helps. How their expand and collapse buttons work.

So is there any way to do this?

Comment: An Expander is what I would use, what exactly do you mean when you say it "isn't quite capable of pulling objects beneath it back up or pushing them back down"?

Comment: You can display any object types you like in a WPF TreeView. This article is very good: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

Comment: I mean it very well hides and displays its contents which is good but I cant seem to get it to push text that is out side of it up or back down.

Comment: +1 for the TreeView. Appart from that, it might be a detail but IMO, hiding "Second name" and "Third name" using an expander-like button next to "First name" is a questionnable user interaction design choice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is an example of using the `Expander` as the way the download page on Microsoft uses it. Note that the `Height` of the `RowDefinitions` is set to `Auto`, otherwise the `Expander` does not collapse when `IsExpanded` is set to false.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
            <TextBlock Height="50" Text="Hello" />
        </Border>
    </Expander>
    <Expander Grid.Row="1" IsExpanded="True">
        <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2">
            <TextBlock Height="50" Text="World" />
        </Border>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

regular tree view can do what you ask.

see this wonderful code-project explanation:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124644/Basic-Understanding-of-Tree-View-in-WPF

Comment: Thanks Nahum. I can confirm the article works well enough. Gave Default the credit though, His solution meant I didn't necessarily have to uproot my code and nearly start over again on the design but I'm positive I'll be using this a lot before I'm done with my project. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

WPF `Expander` component do exactly what you want and it push down other control if hosted in a proper panel. Try using a `StackPanel` for example.